# Unable to align link items side by side inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am unable to align `li` items inside a `div` side by side using flex.

All the links appears vertically but I want them to be horizontally.

```
.provinces {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.provinces-header h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.provinces-items {
  display: flex;
}

.provinces-items ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="provinces">
  <div class="provinces-header">
    <h3>Provinces</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="provinces-items">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Ontario</a></li>
      <li><a href="">British Columbia</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Alberta</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Manitoba</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Nova Scotia</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Saskatchewan</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your CSS to :

```
.provinces {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.provinces-header h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.provinces-items ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.provinces-items ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken the class for the list

```
.provinces-items {
    display: flex;
}
```

should be

```
.provinces-items ul {
    display: flex;
}
```